# use libuv function in node.js 0.12.x

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have written a node.js's c++ addon,i can be complied successfully under node.js 0.10.x. But when migrate it to 0.12.x, it failed when several error,such as `error C2065: “uv_work_t”:undeclared identifier`.I wonder whether i can touch libuv's api in 0.12.x?
The code is showed as follow:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <string>
#include <v8.h>

#ifdef WINDOWS_SPECIFIC_DEFINE
#include <windows.h>
typedef DWORD ThreadId;
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
typedef unsigned int ThreadId;
#endif
using namespace v8;

void async_hello(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args);

//not in main thread，called in uv thread pool
void call_work(uv_work_t* req);

//the callback function
void call_work_after(uv_work_t* req);

static ThreadId __getThreadId() {
    ThreadId nThreadID;
#ifdef WINDOWS_SPECIFIC_DEFINE

    nThreadID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    nThreadID = (nThreadID << 16) + GetCurrentThreadId();
#else
    nThreadID = getpid();
    nThreadID = (nThreadID << 16) + pthread_self();
#endif
    return nThreadID;
}

static void __tsleep(unsigned int millisecond) {
#ifdef WINDOWS_SPECIFIC_DEFINE
    ::Sleep(millisecond);
#else
    usleep(millisecond*1000);
#endif
}

//defined a struct to storage the async reqution information
struct Baton {

    //must be declared as the type of Persistent,when callback finished successfully,execute the function dispose to release.
    Persistent<Function> callback;

    // 
    bool error;
    std::string error_message;

    //save the string passed from js
    std::string input_string;

    //save the string return to js
    std::string result;

};


void async_hello(const Arguments& args) {
    printf("\n%s Thread id : gettid() == %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__getThreadId());
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    if(args.Length() < 2) { 
        ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong number of arguments"))); 
        return; 
      } 


    if (!args[0]->IsString() || !args[1]->IsFunction()) {
        ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
            String::New("Wrong number of arguments")));
        return;
    }


    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[1]);

    Baton* baton = new Baton();
    baton->error = false;
    baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
    v8::String::Utf8Value param1(args[0]->ToString());
    baton->input_string = std::string(*param1); 

    uv_work_t *req = new uv_work_t();
    req->data = baton;

    int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), req, call_work,
                               (uv_after_work_cb)call_work_after);
    assert(status == 0);
    return 
}

//not in main thread
void call_work(uv_work_t* req) {
    printf("\n%s Thread id : gettid() == %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__getThreadId());
    Baton* baton = static_cast<Baton*>(req->data);
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++) {
        __tsleep(1000);
        printf("sleep 1 seconds in uv_work\n");
    }


    baton->result = baton->input_string+ "--->hello world from c++";

}


//return to main thread
void call_work_after(uv_work_t* req) {
    printf("\n%s Thread id : gettid() == %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__getThreadId());    
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Baton* baton = static_cast<Baton*>(req->data);
    if (baton->error) {
        Local<Value> err = Exception::Error(String::New(baton->error_message.c_str()));

        //
        const unsigned argc = 1;
        Local<Value> argv[argc] = { err };

        //
        TryCatch try_catch;

        baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);
        if (try_catch.HasCaught()) {
            node::FatalException(try_catch);
        }
    } else {

        const unsigned argc = 2;
        Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
            Local<Value>::New(Null()),
            Local<Value>::New(String::New(baton->result.c_str()))
        };
        TryCatch try_catch;
        baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);
        if (try_catch.HasCaught()) {
            node::FatalException(try_catch);
        }
    }

    //relase Persistent callback
    baton->callback.Dispose();
    // release the memory space
    delete baton;
    delete req;
}

void RegisterModule(Handle<Object> target) {
    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("async_hello"),FunctionTemplate::New(async_hello)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
```

> I have changed `async_hello`'s paramater,since according to the newest node's API [document](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html),it use `FunctionCallbackInfo`(not `Arguments` used in node.js 0.10.x) to receive js's paramater.The original code is  storage [here](http://git.oschina.net/yunnysunny/async-tutorial-code/blob/master/addon/src/hello.cc), and it can be compiled successfully under node.js 0.10.x.

Comment: Could you post some code? libuv changed between nodejs 0.10 and 0.12, but the work queue had changes at other parts.

Comment: your code is a very nice sample for Async Callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just adding `#include <uv.h>` to the begin of the code can resolve the problem.