# How can I connect my C++ application with an node.js server to get JSON data?

Tags: c++, json, node.js

It's pretty much the tittle. 
Im not expecting the whole code to just copy and paste (but feel free to do it). Im just having difficulties to find some data related. If someone knows how to do it, please post some hints, article links, specific words to make some research on it.
Thank you.

Comment: hint: Poco library, it has all the bits you need to hook up together to do this..

Comment: "connect with a server" = "writing a client". You are asking how to write an HTTP client in C++. And why should the client care in which language the server was written? It may be written in BASIC and you wouldn't notice. That's the point of the web and of internet protocols.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks sr.

Comment: @MaicoWilliams: I cannot tell how serious you are, but there is nothing magic either about Node.js or about a C++ client. The communcation is just HTTP, probably a GET request with a response that contains a header like `Content-Type: application/json`. How the server is implemented *must* be irrelevant for the client. It's like asking *"I want to plug my washing machine's cable into a type C socket. Electricity comes from a coal-fired power plant."*

Comment: I'd just mention that generally I would stay away from c++ client with a Node.js server, an Apache thrift server would be better...

Comment: @ChristianHackl Im pretty serious, dude. I just don't understand why you was mad on your first answer. It was just a question. I'm not very familiar with C++ using server data. But thanks for your answer. Now I know what I should be researching.

Comment: @BabraCunningham Thanks man. Im still trying to define the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Christian mentioned in his comment, your problem can be solved by implementing an HTTP client that parses JSON responses, independently of the technology used by your server. To do this in C++, I would refer you to the following resources:

- [High-level library for C++ HTTP client](https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp).
- [`libcurl`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (lower level library for HTTP requests).
- [RapidJSON](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson) library to parse the responses you will get from your server (see [this benchmark](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark) for a comparison of JSON parsing libraries).

If your C++ application uses a framework such as Qt, it likely includes facilities for requests (e.g. [Qt HTTP example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html)).

On the server side, you will have to define HTTP endpoints that return the data you are interested in, encoded as JSON. The beginning of [this tutorial](https://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-simple-webservice-in-nodejs/) shows an easy way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. After his answer I have found some info even by myself.  This one is nice too: https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp

Answer (score 2):

node.js c++ add on manual

https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

http://libuv.org/

[use libuv function in node.js 0.12.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141137/use-libuv-function-in-node-js-0-12-x)